# how to combine/merge multiple generic fields/columns in one field/column with average calculation per generic field/column values in Splunk?

Tags: splunk

I have following situation in splunk (see picture below).

[image: Actual Situation]

I need following pattern in Splunk (see picture below).

[image: Target Situation]

I have different generic columns where the last part of the column-name (Suffix) is dynamic and unknown. I need to combine/merge this generic columns to one target-column. Within the target-column I want to calculate the average per generic field. I think the picture explains the situation very well.

Comment: Please include your images into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there are a number of ways to get to your desired point... I'm somewhat curious as to the search that got you to your initial point, as there might be some better options where you may be able to reach your desired output without the intermediate point as I'll demonstrate here...

First I'm going to give you a base search, that I'm going to work with... This sets up a mock data set based on yours but without aggregations.

```
| makeresults 
| eval raw=split("10.10.2016 05:55 SuffixA=17
10.10.2016 05:57 SuffixA=15
10.10.2016 05:55 SuffixB=16
10.10.2016 05:59 SuffixB=12
10.10.2016 06:01 SuffixB=11
10.10.2016 06:03 SuffixC=9
10.10.2016 06:05 SuffixC=18
10.10.2016 06:09 SuffixC=21","
") 
| mvexpand raw | rename raw -> _raw 
| rex "^(?<_time>\S+\s+\S+)" | eval _time=strptime(_time,"%m.%d.%Y %H:%M") 
| kv | table _time Suffix*
```

From here I have just the Suffixes and their corresponding values at certain data points. To calculate the aggregations per suffix, it would be handy if I could transform this into a key (being the particular suffix in use) and a value... which is what [untable](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/untable) would do for me. ( For the curious, the opposite direction is of course [xyseries](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/xyseries) )

```
<base search> | untable _time key value
```

Now I just need to perform the aggregations by key, in your case average. And I want to preserve all the original rows, across the original data set, so this is where [eventstats](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/eventstats) would be handy

```
<base search> | untable _time key value
| eventstats avg(value) as average by key
```

I now have an output of _time, key, value, average. Next to get your separate suffix columns back, I can use a syntax trick of [eval](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/eval) and assign a field named for the value of another field, and use [fields](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/fields) to remove the now superflous fields.

```
<base search> | untable _time key value
| eventstats avg(value) as average by key
| eval {key}=value | fields - key value
```

---

After the above experiment, let's use some of our above tricks, to make a new base search that matches your current state above.

```
| makeresults | eval raw=split("10.10.2016 05:55 SuffixA=17
10.10.2016 05:57 SuffixA=15
10.10.2016 05:55 SuffixB=16
10.10.2016 05:59 SuffixB=12
10.10.2016 06:01 SuffixB=11
10.10.2016 06:03 SuffixC=9
10.10.2016 06:05 SuffixC=18
10.10.2016 06:09 SuffixC=21","
") | mvexpand raw | rename raw -> _raw 
| rex "^(?<_time>\S+\s+\S+)" | eval _time=strptime(_time,"%m.%d.%Y %H:%M") 
| kv | table _time Suffix* | untable _time key value 
| eventstats avg(value) as average by key 
| eval {key}=value, StaticPart:{key}=average | fields - key value average 
| table _time StaticPart:* Suffix*
```

from this point, another option may be to use [foreach](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/foreach) to run an eval across all of the StaticPart:* fields to create a new average field, and the remove all the StaticPart fields like so:

```
<base search> 
| foreach StaticPart:* [eval average=coalesce('<<FIELD>>',average)] 
| fields - StaticPart:*
```